# Preview to pop up a picture every time I open a program - bash command

Tags: bash, terminal

I would like a picture (jpeg of  a samosa) to open in preview every time I open Google Chrome. Is there a terminal command which will allow this to happen?

macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: macOS Sierra 10.12.6